# Integral of $\exp⁡(-j\sin⁡(t))$ over $[0,T]$

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I have to solve the following integral :
$$
\int_0^T \exp\left(-j \sin(t)\right) \,\mathrm{d}t
$$
 where $j=\sqrt{−1}$

How do I proceed to solve this?

Comment: The function you're attempting to integrate doesn't seem to have a "closed form" antiderivative.  Do you need an exact solution, or is a numerical approximation enough?

Comment: Also, what exactly is $T$ here?  Is $T = 2\pi$?  If so, then [according to WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+exp(-i+sin(t))+dt+from+0+to+2+pi), your answer can be written in terms of Bessel functions.

Comment: T is not 2π, how do I solve it? I want an expression like that which I can use further

Comment: As I said, there is no such expression (no closed form) for this integral.  The best you can do is get an approximation

Comment: and how is that?

Answer (score 1):

$e^{i\sin t}$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function (and an entire function) with the following Fourier series:

$$ e^{i\sin t} = J_0(1) + 2i\sum_{n\geq 0}J_{2n+1}(1)\sin((2n+1)t)+2\sum_{n\geq 1}J_{2n}(1) \cos(2nt) \tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \int_{0}^{T}e^{i\sin t}\,dt = T\cdot J_0(1)+2i\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{J_{2n+1}(1)}{2n+1}-2i\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{J_{2n+1}}{2n+1}\cos((2n+1)T)+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{J_{2n}(1)}{n}\sin(2nT)\tag{2} $$
where $J_\nu$ is a [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), so that $J_\nu(1)$ behaves like $\frac{1}{\nu! 2^\nu}$ and
$$ J_0(1)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n n!^2}\approx\frac{88}{115}.\tag{3}$$